# How can I mantain some part of the code running all the time?

Tags: python-3.x

Basically what I wanna know is the question!
I wanna put some code running all the time, when the other code is simultaneously running.

Comment: Be more specific perhaps? You put the section of code you want to run all the time in a loop. Perhaps you need to use threads.

Comment: I was serching and I don't found what I want in the threads. I want, to be more specific, for example: you have something that you want moving all the time, and simultaneously the rest of code is running doing diferents things.